# H and V don't work on windows server 2012 log on

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, drivers, keyboard

I'd like to log in to windows server 2012. It worked yesterday but today I couldn't enter my current password because the `H` and `V` keys didn't work and my password includes the `h`.

I connected another keyboard, however, the issue didn't solve. I connected the current keyboard to another system and it worked correctly. Also, the `On-screen keyboard`'s `H` and `V` keys didn't work.

I think that it's driver's issues.

I try to restart the server but I couldn't because the setting that called [Shutdown: Allow system to be shut down without having to log on](http://suretalent.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-shutdown-windows-2008-without.html) hasn't been enabled yet.

So, what am I doing?

Any helps, appreciated.

Comment: If you have a numeric keypad on your keyboard you can try to use the ASCII code: ALT+072 (H) or ALT+104 (h). Keep the ALT key pressed while entering the numbers on the key pad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a numeric keypad on your keyboard you can try to use the ASCII code: <kbd>Alt+072</kbd> for `H` or <kbd>ALT+104</kbd> for `h`. Keep the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key pressed while entering the numbers on the key pad.

You can enter any Unicode characters this way. I often use exotic Unicode characters in my passwords.

Comment: I cannot imagine he will use these ASCII codes every time when logging in. This is helpful post, but it's not a permanent solution. There must be something rotten in his Windows Server OS and it should be more investigated if problem wont be solved after first successful log in.